# What is going wrong with my code(python) when I try to convert it into a stand alone application using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python

When I place my code into auto-py-to-exe and run it, it runs it into a file. When I try to open it, it opens but immediately quits(I'm using Mac).

I'm unsure what to try, as i've found no helpful answer yet.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
```

## Creates a calculation from the given input to give a pay for output

```
def calculate ():
    try:
        num1 = price.get()
        num2 = markUp.get()
        num3 = quantity.get()
        total =(float(num1) + float(num2))
        total1 = (total * float(num3))
        total2 = (total1 * .1 + total1)
        price.delete(0, END)
        markUp.delete(0, END)
        quantity.delete(0, END)
        listbox.insert(0,total1)
        listbox1.insert(0,total2)
    except: 
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Only numbers are accepted")

def clear ():
     try:
        listbox.delete(0, END)
        listbox1.delete(0, END)
     except: 
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Only numbers are accepted")
```

## Sets up main window and names the window Pay Calculator

```
  root = Tk()
    root.title("Pay Calculator")
```

## Creates empty frame

```
 content = ttk.Frame(root)
```

## Create a smaller frame within the frame

```
frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", 
width=100, height=100)
frame1 = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", 
width=100, height=100)
```

## Creates widgets

```
namelbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Price Calculator")
pricelbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Enter price of one tyre")
markUplbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Enter mark up")
quantitylbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Enter quantity")
withoutGSTlbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Price without GST")
withGSTlbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Price including GST")
price = ttk.Entry(content)
markUp = ttk.Entry(content)
quantity = ttk.Entry(content)

listbox = Listbox(frame, width=20, height=10)
listbox1 = Listbox(frame1, width=20, height=10)
```

## Creates a "Calculate" button and calls the calculate code

```
calculate = ttk.Button(content, text="Calculate",command=calculate)
clear = ttk.Button(content, text="Clear",command=clear)
```

## Position widgets on the grid

```
listbox.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan=2)
listbox1.grid(column=0,row=3, columnspan=2)

content.grid(column=0, row=0)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=3)
frame1.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=2, rowspan=3)

price.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=2)
markUp.grid(column=3, row=3, columnspan=2)
quantity.grid(column=3, row=5, columnspan=2)

namelbl.grid(column=3, row=0, columnspan=2,padx=20, pady=20)
pricelbl.grid(column=3, row=2, columnspan=2)
markUplbl.grid(column=3, row=4, columnspan=2)
quantitylbl.grid(column=3, row=6, columnspan=2)
withoutGSTlbl.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2)
withGSTlbl.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=2)

calculate.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=1)
clear.grid(column=1, row=7, columnspan=1)
```

## Continue looping until we close the main window

```
root.mainloop()
```

I want to be able to click on the file and make it run without showing the code, also if possible run on other platforms(windows).

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable like k or m or any other you want, now just add this piece of code at the end of your program

```
k=input("press close to exit")
```

Here I just assumed k as variable to pause the program, you can use any variable you like.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory "/var/folders/fz/8hcphqms2fb38w86nt91j7s1vx21kt/T/_MEIVS9znO/tcl" not found.
[27461] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter
logout
Still having same result, this is what I found in the console when I ran through the console.